# How to apply multi classes to an element/ combine conditional static classes

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I want to apply multiple css classes to one element. How do I do it? One conditional and one static.

```
  <p
    class={current === 'overview' ? 'selected' : '' // here I want to add another class named foo}
    on:click={() => (current = 'overview')}
  >
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make life easier you can use the `class:` directive

```html
<p class="foo" class:selected={current === 'overview'}>
```

Answer (score 2):

Separate by whitespace according to [HTML standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html) `class="{current === 'overview' ? 'selected' : ''} foo"`

Comment: Oh damn this is goated. For brevity you can also write `current === 'overview' && 'selected'` so you don't need the ternary thing, if you're fine with a rogue "false" class chilling on your component whenever the condition is not met. Doesn't matter imo.